# Layout.tsx does not work as it should on all pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, next.js

The code that I put in console.log() to show the page path only appears in the "pages.tsx" file (src/app/pages.tsx) and the others that are in (src/page/Login) are not appearing in the console.

layout.tsx code:

```
'use client';

import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';
import './globals.css';
import { checkIsPublicRoute } from '@/functions/check-is-public-route';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {

  const pathname = usePathname();
  console.log("caminho:", pathname)
  const isPublicPage = checkIsPublicRoute(pathname!)
  console.log(isPublicPage)

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

When I navigate between the pages I created, nothing appears in the end but on the main page of next it appears:

```
caminho: /
layout.tsx:19 false
layout.tsx:17 caminho: /
layout.tsx:19 false
layout.tsx:17 caminho: /
layout.tsx:19 false
layout.tsx:17 caminho: /
layout.tsx:19 false
```

Regardless of the route I take, it doesn't capture what the layout is defining

Answer (score 0):

The pages/ folder does not have priority over the app folder, so you need to create a _app.tsx inside the pages folder to function as layout.tsx